# UIDocument/Xcode configuration

Tags: swift, uidocument

I am trying to follow this tutorial...

https://www.raywenderlich.com/131668/document-provider-tutorial

I got to this part ...

[image]

But I cannot figure out where I find this in Xcode 8.0 which means I get this error message ...

[image]

Sorry I am sure this is an easy question? Looking at the finished project, it reconised Note as type, yet I cannot seem to see the class in the starter project!! driving me mad!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bon, you learn something everyday... went thru this six or more times but at last noticed Note.swift missing here from Starter Project Instructions, obvious isn't it, not.

[image]